# Delta Compression of Stream

Tags: stream, compression

I would like to use delta compression to compress a stream of data. I expect this to be very efficient, because it's a stream of increasing 32bit integers.

There seems plenty of libraries for creating a delta between two binary objects, but I couldn't find anything for stream encoding.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your question isn't about delta compression specifically, but "How can I compress a stream of increasing integers?"  Delta compression is involved in some algorithms, but other algorithms don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the [JavaFastPFOR](https://github.com/lemire/JavaFastPFOR) library, which provides simple delta encoding in the `me.lemire.integercompression.Delta` class, delta-based algorithms that compress blocks of integers, and other algorithms for compressing integer arrays.  This library claims to have been optimized for speed (based on a C++ library with speed goals) and the GitHub readme offers scholarly papers documenting its algorithms.